# python Curses getkey returns no input when I used direction keys

Tags: python, curses

I made a game using the terminal and pythons curses module.  I steer the snake using the kbinput function.  This works great for the number pad and the standard letters, however, when I try to use the direction keys it throws the exception `_cureses_error: no input`  If I hold the keys down eventually one of the commands will get through eventually.  I have it in full blocking mode, so it makes no sense to get the no input exception.

I tried a quick test to see if having it running in a thread was a problem, but in my test case the direction keys work fine.

relevant functions are below:

```
def game():
    screen=curses.initscr()
    curses.start_color()
    curses.raw()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.noecho()
    screen.keypad(True)
    try:
        gtime=time.time()
        b=Board(screen)
        s=Snake(b)
        #thread.start_new_thread(steps,(s,b))
        thread.start_new_thread(kbinput,(s,b,screen))
        ....

def kbinput(snake,b,screen):
    while snake.alive==True:
        key=""
        key=screen.getkey()
        b.key=key
        if key=="q":
            snake.alive=False
            break
        elif (key == "8" or key == "i" or key == 'KEY_UP') and snake.direction != 3: snake.direction=1
        elif (key == "6" or key == "l" or key == 'KEY_RIGHT') and snake.direction != 4: snake.direction=2
        elif (key == "4" or key == "j" or key == 'KEY_LEFT') and snake.direction != 2: snake.direction=4
        elif (key == "5" or key == "k" or key == 'KEY_DOWN') and snake.direction != 1: snake.direction=3
    return
```

EDIT:
Thomas was correct that the problem seems to be with threading the kbinput.  To fix the problem I made these changes to the functions:

```
def game():
    screen=curses.initscr()
    curses.start_color()
    curses.raw()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.noecho()
    screen.keypad(True)
    curses.halfdelay(1)
    curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_RED,curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2,curses.COLOR_GREEN,curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    try:
        gtime=time.time()
        b=Board(screen)
        s=Snake(b)
        #thread.start_new_thread(kbinput,(s,b,screen))
        while s.alive and s.x != 0 and s.x != b.width-1 and s.y !=1 and  s.y != b.height-2:
            kbinput(s,b,screen)
            gtime=time.time()
            update(s,b,screen)
            if snake_check(s) == True: break

def kbinput(snake,b,screen):
    #while snake.alive==True:
        key=""
        key2=screen.getch()
        if key2==-1: return
        try:key=chr(key2)
        except:pass
        if key=="q":
            snake.alive=False
            #break
        elif (key == "8" or key == "i" or key2 == curses.KEY_UP) and snake.direction != 3: snake.direction=1
        elif (key == "6" or key == "l" or key2 == curses.KEY_RIGHT) and snake.direction != 4: snake.direction=2
        elif (key == "4" or key == "j" or key2 == curses.KEY_LEFT) and snake.direction != 2: snake.direction=4
        elif (key == "5" or key == "k" or key2 == curses.KEY_DOWN) and snake.direction != 1: snake.direction=3
        return
```

Comment: @Thomas Dickey was right below.  For people looking for a way to get keyboard input, use the curses.halfdealy(n) function between screen refreshes and God help you if you need refresh rates < 1/10 of second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than look for a string-literal

```
key == 'KEY_UP')
```

look for the defined-constant

```
key == curses.KEY_UP)
```

although as noted in a comment, that requires the `getch` method.

However, this line indicates a more serious problem:

```
thread.start_new_thread(kbinput,(s,b,screen))
```

Curses in general is not thread-safe (and python's curses-binding is subject to that limitation):

- [Why does (fill in the blank) happen when I use two threads?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread)

Comment: Firstly I'd have to use screen.getch() for this to work as it is a number comparison.  I did do that and I still get the same behavior without the error message (I can't see it well because the program is constantly redrawing the screen so the error message gets over written  almost instantly.

Comment: it does seem to be a problem with the threading.  Interesting as I had a test script that just ran the threading part and it was fine.  It must have been some interaction between the other curses calls and my thread...